# What is Austria?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

IF

> New Zealand is 64
>
> Argentina is 54
>
> Then Austria is??   Need **Two** answers with explanation

NO PARTIAL ANSWERS PLEASE

Comment: Johnny has two apples. Jerry has three pears. And Georgia has a peach. From this, derive a complete unified field theory of physics. Give three examples Show your work.

Comment: Who is Spain? Why is Hitler? When is right?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If New Zealand is 64 and Argentina is 54, then Austria is:

> **43** or **34**

Since:

> 1. The international dialling codes for these countries are +64 (New Zealand), +54 (Argentina) and **+43** (Austria);

and

> 2. There are 6 consonants and 4 vowels in 'NEW ZEALAND', 5 consonants and 4 vowels in 'ARGENTINA', and **3 consonants and 4 vowels** in 'AUSTRIA'.

Comment: Ooooooh nice I did not see that second answer at all lol, well done!!

Comment: Now I'm curious.  Do any other countries have this property?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman After a quick scan down the two-digit list, I can't spot any others. There are a few 'near misses' (like France: 33 vs 42), but there's a huge amount of 3-digit countries who aren't even eligible for this right off the bat... Looks like these 2 might be the only ones (though I'm sure someone might be able to devise different valid rules based on some other criteria instead...).

Comment: if you ask the Catalans how its spelled, Espanya: 34 would work

Comment: @Deem.The countries Greece ,Latvia, Serbia all of them have 3 vowels and 3 consonants

Comment: @VassilisParassidis Yes, but none of those countries has the international dialling code +33 (that’s France, which has four consonants and two vowels).

Comment: quick someone call the ITU-T and tell them we need to make a change!

Comment: @Hatman *y* isn’t a vowel in *Espanya* (in fact it’s not even a semivowel) ust like *g* isn’t a vowel in *lasagna*